# How to make a check-box in a dynamic MFC dialog?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have to create a dynamic dialog and used therefor the procedure described in the article [Creating a Template in Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#template_in_memory). I already created buttons and edits but I don't know how I can make check-box. Do you know how?

In the [DLGITEMTEMPLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article there are only following types defined:

- `0x0080` Button
- `0x0081` Edit
- `0x0082` Static
- `0x0083` List box
- `0x0084` Scroll bar
- `0x0085` Combo box

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A checkbox is a Button with the BS_CHECKBOX or BS_AUTOCHECKBOX style

for more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

A checkbox is a button with the BS_CHECKBOX style.